# How do I make multiple balls drop from the top?

Tags: java, android-studio

```
public class MovingBagView extends View {

    private Bitmap bag[] = new Bitmap[2];
    private int bagX;
    private int bagY = 1000;
    private int bagSpeed;
    private Boolean touch = false;
    private int canvasWidth, canvasHeight;
    private int yellowX = 500, yellowY, yellowSpeed = -16;
    private Paint yellowPaint = new Paint();
    private int score;
    private Bitmap backgroundImage;
    private Paint scorePaint = new Paint();
    private Bitmap life[] = new Bitmap[2];

    public MovingBagView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        bag[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bag1);
        bag[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bag2);
        backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);
        yellowPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        yellowPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        scorePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        scorePaint.setTextSize(40);
        scorePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        scorePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        life[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.heart);
        life[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.heart_grey);
        bagX = 10;
        score = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
        canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
        canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
        int minBagX = bag[0].getWidth();
        int maxBagX = canvasWidth - bag[0].getWidth() * 2;
        bagX = bagX + bagSpeed;
        if (bagX < minBagX) {
            bagX = minBagX;
        }
        if (bagX >= maxBagX) {
            bagX = maxBagX;
        }
        bagSpeed = bagSpeed + 2;
        if (touch) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bag[1], bagX, bagY, null);
        }
        else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bag[0], bagX, bagY, null);
        }
        yellowY = yellowY - yellowSpeed;
        if (hitBallChecker(yellowX, yellowY)) {
            score = score + 10;
            yellowY = -100;
        }
        if (yellowY < 0) {
            yellowY = canvasHeight + 21;
            yellowX = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxBagX - minBagX)) + maxBagX;
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(yellowX, yellowY, 15, yellowPaint);
        canvas.drawText("Score : " + score, 20, 60, scorePaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(life[0], 500, 10, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(life[0], 570, 10, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(life[0], 640, 10, null);
    }

    public boolean hitBallChecker(int x, int y) {
        if (bagY < y && y < (bagY + bag[0].getHeight()) && bagX < x && x < (bagX + bag[0].getWidth())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            touch = true;
            bagSpeed = -22;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I've figured out how to make the balls drop from the top of the screen. The code is supposed to make multiple yellow balls drop from the top of the screen, but only one yellow ball drops. Random yellow balls are supposed to drop from the top, and they drop from different positions. You can see the preview of it below:

[image]

Comment: What did you try to do here: `yellowX = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxBagX - minBagX)) + maxBagX;` ? Maybe try to replace `+ maxBagX`by `+ minBagX`
Also I think you need to rethink your Y axis. Because as far as i understood your code, the top of the window is y=0 and the bottom is y=height. Why do you check if y has negative value ?

Comment: I've changed the code to `minBagX` and it does nothing. Where did I do `yellowY = 0`, I don't see it in my code?

Comment: You initialize Y to -16 and the speed is -16 then you make Y evoles with `y = y-speed`. So Y is greater and greater. Meanwhile your ball is going from top to bottom so I guess that the top of your screen is Y=0 and the bottom is Y=height. Now you want to reset the ball when it goes out of the screen. Instead of doing that, you do `if y<0 then y=height` which literally is teleporting your ball out of your screen. You are lucky for the first iteration because Y is exactly equal to 0.

Comment: How do I resolve this problem? How do I stop the ball from resetting?

Comment: Try to understand what you are doing, print the important values at each step to understand the impact of each iteration on your variables. As I pointed out I think you misunderstood the Y axis, focus on that when you reinitialize the ball.

Answer (score 0):

To implement this, you should consider creating a custom object `Ball`

```
public class Ball{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int speed;

    public Ball(int x, int y, int speed){
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
         this.speed = speed;
    }
}
```

Then you can add multiple Balls in an ArrayList and in the `draw()` you iterate through every Ball in the array and do what you've been doing to one Ball with each.

```
for(int i = 0; i < balls.length(); i++){
    Ball ball = balls.get(i);
    ball.y -= ball.speed;
    // check for collisions
    // draw ball
}
```

Comment: Why do I get an error when I use the variable `ball` in the for loop?

Comment: I edited my code to fix a typo which was probably causing that issue.

Comment: I still get an error for the variable `balls` in the for loop? It says `cannot resolve symbol 'balls'`